# How to reclaim free space after attempting to resize Windows partition with GParted

Tags: macos, partitioning, boot-camp, gparted

This is on an OS X Macbook Air with a Boot Camp partition

I had a working Win7 boot camp partition that was too small. Being lazy, I googled how to resize it and got a guide for GParted. I successfully took some space from the OS X partition and made it free, moved it around and added it to the NTFS partition. Then I got the dreaded "Missing Operating System" message. I then tried "gptsync /dev/sda" and it suggested a fix, I accepted. Still nothing.

Now, I decided to use Boot Camp Assistant to delete the boot camp partition and then when it came to reclaiming the space all into the OS X partition, it failed. I cannot resize the partition. I can't use the free space. How do I get it so I can just use the ~40GB free space to re-install Windows 8.1 (usb with tools ready to go).

Cheers

```
localhost:~ q$ sudo gpt -r -vv show disk0  
Password:  
gpt show: disk0: mediasize=121332826112; sectorsize=512; blocks=236978176  
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0  
gpt show: disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1  
gpt show: disk0: Sec GPT at sector 236978175  
      start       size  index  contents  
          0          1         MBR  
          1          1         Pri GPT header  
          2         32         Pri GPT table  
         34          6           
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B  
     409640   81698776           
   82108416  153600000      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC  
  235708416    1267712      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC  
  236976128       2015           
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table  
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header  

localhost:~ q$ diskutil resizevolume /dev/disk0s2 limits  
For device disk0s2 Macintosh HD:  
        Current size:  78.6 GB (78643200000 Bytes)  
        Minimum size:  54.1 GB (54125408256 Bytes)  
        Maximum size:  78.6 GB (78643200000 Bytes)
```

Also, gptsync seems to have changed the partition type of the Recovery partition from "Apple_Boot" to "Apple_HFS"

```
localhost:~ x$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            78.6 GB    disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD             649.1 MB   disk0s3
```

I have tried booting into single user mode and running "/sbin/fsck -fy" and it found an error and corrected it. I then ran Disk Utility repair permissions and then Verify Disk and it found no errors.